# How to get selected option from React MUI Autocomplete with rendered content?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to get selected option from Autocomplete built with renderOption, each option has online/offline status and nickname.

```
  const renderOption = (props, option) => {
    console.log(props.key); // nickname here
    const color = option.status ? 'green' : 'red';
    return (
      <Box key={props.key} display="flex" justifyContent="start" alignItems="center" sx={{
          padding: '0 15px', 
          cursor: 'pointer', 
          '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor:'#d6edff'
        }}}>
        <Box width={10} height={10} marginRight={5} borderRadius="50%" bgcolor={color} />
        <div>{option.nickname}</div>
      </Box>
    );
  };

    <Autocomplete   
      options={options}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.nickname}
      renderOption={renderOption} 
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} 
        variant="outlined" 
        sx={{
            width: '15rem',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            '& input': {
              height: '25px',
              padding: 0
            },
            '& label': {
              transform: 'none',
              marginTop: 8,
              marginLeft: 10              
            },
            '& .MuiInputBase-root': { padding: 0 },
            '& legend': { display: 'none' }
          }}
          label="Список участников"
      />}
      onInputChange={updateSearch}
      onChange={(event, value) => console.log('onChange', value)}
      onSelect={(event, value) => console.log('onSelect', event, value)}
    />
```

If I omit renderOption and fill options with strings only - onChange is being fired and I can get the value. With renderedOption onSelect fired, but value is undefined and event.target is an input but not the option. Any workaround would be highly appeciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly, I managed to do it with onClick:

```
  const userSelected = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.innerText);
  }

<Box key={props.key} onClick={userSelected}
```